# Haskell Float to Int to Float conversion Error

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I want to convert the a Floating Point Number (0,123456) and round it with b (positive whole number).
I use the truncate function to round the Floating point number to a specific length "b"

This is the formula i came up with, however I get an error when compiling with the GHCI

The Function:

```
calcFloatingNum:: Double -> Int -> Int -> Float
calcFloatingNum a b = truncate ( a * 10^b) /10^b
```

The Error Code:

```
   * No instance for (Integral Double)
        arising from a use of `truncate'
    * In the first argument of `(/)', namely `truncate (a * 10 ^ b)'
      In the expression: truncate (a * 10 ^ b) / 10 ^ b
      In an equation for `calcFloatingNum':
          calcFloatingNum a b = truncate (a * 10 ^ b) / 10 ^ b
   |
10 | calcFloatingNum a b = truncate ( a * 10^b) /10^b
```

And if I try anyway it states:

```
ghci> calcFloatingNum 0.2345 2

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    Variable not in scope: calcFloatingNum :: t0 -> t1 -> t
ghci>
```

So the Signature might be the problem, however I can't seem to find the solution.

I tried converting the numbers with "fromInteger" and "toInteger", however it resulted in Error codes as well.

Comment: If you get an error then your library will not be loaded, so none of the functions you define will be in scope. That explains the error you get in GHCi.

Comment: Your type signature says the function takes three inputs: `Double`, `Int`, and `Int`, but your definition only lists `a` and `b` as arguments. This seems unintentional.

Comment: I'd recommend using only a single floating point type. And `Double` is generally better supported, so I'd suggest changing the `Float` in your type signature to `Double`.

Comment: The first thing I would say is that if you truncate the number you have lost the information you need to round correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the things I mentioned in my comments, this question is really an exercise in following the types and in particular the floating and integral types.

Let's start off with the type signatures of the functions that you are attempting to use. I'll use concrete types to keep things simple.

```
truncate :: Double -> Int
(^) :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

As you can see these functions produce integers, while you want floats. So whenever we use these function we need to use `fromIntegral :: Int -> Double` to convert the result back into `Double`:

```
calcFloatingNum:: Double -> Int -> Double
calcFloatingNum a b = 
  fromIntegral (truncate (a * fromIntegral (10 ^ b))) / fromIntegral (10 ^ b)
```